# Removing first newline preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, bbcode

I'm writing some PHP to convert BBcode to HTML.

I would like to convert this BBcode:

```
[quote]
Hello World
[/quote]
```

to the following:

```
<blockquote>Hello World</blockquote>
```

The preg_replace function that I'm using to perform this is:

```
preg_replace("/\[quote\](.+?)\[\/quote\]/s", "<blockquote>\\1</blockquote>", $bbCode);
```

This almost does everything I need it to, but my problem is that it carries through the \n's from before and after 'Hello World', and produces:

```
<blockquote>
Hello World
</blockquote>
```

Any ideas how I could fix this? All help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
/\[quote\]\s*(.+?)\s*\[\/quote\]/s
```

Comment: It works! :)

I was sure I had already tried something like that but obviously not.

Thanks very much Gumbo

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape backslashes inside of double-quotes. Instead of "\[", you need "\\[".

Answer (score 0):

A possibility would be to use the  '`e`' [regex-modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), to call, for instance, the `trim` function on the string.

Quoting that page of the manual :

> **e** (`PREG_REPLACE_EVAL`) 
> If this modifier is set, `preg_replace()`
>   does normal substitution of
>   backreferences in the replacement
>   string, evaluates it as PHP code, and
>   uses the result for replacing the
>   search string. Single quotes, double
>   quotes, backslashes (`\`) and `NULL`
>   chars will be escaped by backslashes
>   in substituted backreferences.
>
> Only `preg_replace()` uses this
>   modifier; it is ignored by other PCRE
>   functions.

For instance, this code, only slightly different from yours :

```
$bbCode = <<<STR
[quote]
Hello World
[/quote]
STR;

$output = preg_replace("/\[quote\](.+?)\[\/quote\]/es", "'<blockquote>' . trim('\\1') . '</blockquote>'", $bbCode);
var_dump($output);
```

Would give you :

```
string '<blockquote>Hello World</blockquote>' (length=36)
```

ie, the [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) function is called on what was matched -- note it will remove all white-spaces at the beginning and end of your string ; not only newlines, but also spaces and tabulations.

*(For instance, you can take a look at Example #4 on the [manual page of `preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace))*

*(It's maybe a bit overkill in this case, should I add -- but it's nice to know anyway)*